Filtering rows that starts and/or end in a specific numeric value
I have this data set in R:



col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6




148210.1
448521.3
955635.9
585212.1
558542.3
125312.6


854213.5
125896.5
487951.2
121545.6
125894.6
154215.9


232323.2
454586.3
NA
NA
NA
NA



I need to keep all values that start with the number 1, drop all NA's. Ideally in a single column in a new data frame.
Output would be like this:
New_DF <- Col 1  
         148210.1  
         125312.6  
         125896.5  
         121545.6   
         125894.6     
         154215.9    

Then i would need to add up all the values after the point of New_DF excluding the ones that end at the number 9 (note that there is no 7 or 8 after the point).
Output would be like this:
x = 1+6+5+6+6 = 24
Then i would need to get the mean and IQR but that i'd know how to do. I tried putting it in matrix. numeric. characters. all i could think of :(
I have battled with this for around 4 hours. Thanks in advance to the hero that helps me.

What did you try and what did not work? That would serve as a good starting point for potential answers. Please edit this question and ad your failed code with expected final output (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9462095 for neat tips).

I don't know if you need your intermediate New_df or not, but you can create it like this:
New_df <- pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>% filter(substr(value,1,1)=="1")

Then, to add up, you can do the following:
x = pull(New_df, value) %% 1
sum(x[which(x<=0.8)]*10)

If you don't need the intermediate New_df, you might consider another very similar approach:
x = c(as.matrix(df))
x = x[substr(x,1,1)=="1"] %% 1
sum(x[which(x<=0.8)]*10)


Hello! thanks for your answer.. i´m on a train right now and unable to try it right away. I don't really need the intermediate, sorry if i wasnt that clear

i will update as soon as i try it

Hello again! first part works perfectly and i even get the intermediary new_df. Then when i am trying to add up i get an error: " Error in pull(new_df, value)%%1 :
non-numeric argument to binary operator". Am i doing something wrong?

thanks man! i solved the problem with an adaptation of your answer and @andreWildberg 's answer. Appreciate it!
